# T-SQL - Using a parameter in where and clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameter-passing, case, conditional-statements

I want to pass a parameter and depending on its value I want to evaluate a condition like this:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
DECLARE @Operation INTEGER = 0;

WITH CTEMycte AS
(
    SELECT   
        Table1.Field1,
        Table1.Field2,Table1.Field3
    FROM     
        Table1
    WHERE    
        Table1.Field2 = 1
)
SELECT Field1
FROM CTEMycte
WHERE somecondtion 
  AND 
    CASE WHEN @Operation = 0 THEN [CTEMycte].[Field3] >= 100
         WHEN @Operation = 1 THEN [CTEMycte].[Field3] <= 100 
         WHEN @Operation = 2 THEN [CTEMycte].[Field3] = 100 
    END
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @TrippKinetics It doesn't work because you cannot have condition after `THEN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have condition after `THEN`.You can use `OR`:

```
WHERE somecondtion 
  AND (
   (@Operation = 0 AND [CTEMycte].[Field3] >= 100)
   OR
   (@Operation = 1 AND [CTEMycte].[Field3] <= 100) 
   OR
   (@Operation = 2 AND [CTEMycte].[Field3] = 100 )
  )
```

Alternatively you can combine condition in `WHEN` part:

```
WHERE somecondtion AND
     (CASE WHEN @Operation = 0 AND [CTEMycte].[Field3] >= 100 THEN 1
           WHEN @Operation = 1 AND [CTEMycte].[Field3] <= 100 THEN 1
           WHEN @Operation = 2 AND [CTEMycte].[Field3] = 100  THEN 1
           ELSE 0
      END) = 1
```

Comment: Works like a charm and good to know this for future. Cheers lad2025